# string not analyzed correctly in MarkLogic

Tags: regex, xquery, marklogic

My goal is to analyze a postal code and to identify the separate parts using a regular expression and the analyze-string function.

I use MarkLogic 10. Using the regex to match validates the example below correctly. However, when I use it to analyze the string it fails to identify the various groups correctly:

```
(: analyze dutch postal code :)
let $regex := "^[1-9]\d{3}([A-Z]{2}(\d+(\S+)?)?)?$"
return fn:analyze-string("1234AA11bis", $regex)
```

it returns the following :

```
<s:analyze-string-result xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<s:match>1234<s:group nr="1">AA<s:group nr="2">1<s:group nr="3">1bis</s:group></s:group></s:group>
</s:match>
</s:analyze-string-result>
```

I expect it to return '11' as the value of group nr 2 and 'bis' as the result of group nr 3.

I used some online regex analyzers that return the correct result. Am I missing some flag or something or is this just a bug in MarkLogic?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Could you describe the goal of your regex in plain english? Often that helps to spot issues.

Comment: I would say it is a bug, the `AA` is correctly collected as matching `[A-Z]{2}` and the following `\d+` should collect both digits `11` and not only the first one.

Comment: Fixed match pattern, not the same case..

Comment: @ChristianBaumann Rephrased the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the specs have to say about nested greedy patterns, but there is an easy fix:

```
let $regex := "^[1-9]\d{3}([A-Z]{2}(\d+([^\d\s]+)?)?)?$"
return fn:analyze-string("1234AA11bis", $regex)
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, that helps. The regex mentioned is an official one provided by the government. Still wondering why the output of ML differs from other engines.

Comment: Indeed, it's always best to make the regex unambiguous, rather than relying on greediness or non-greediness.